# Developing iOS apps for other comapnies and upload them

Tags: ios

If I develop and app for a non-tech company for whom it will be an effort (i.e. non-IT people) to get their own Apple iOS developer ID, can I upload it myself under my company ID?

The reason I ask is that it appears to be the norm among other similar companies doing apps for other companies. (At least in the segment/niche I am planning on entering)

In appstore they list: "Developer **dev-company** Copyright **for-company** and the app is associated to their account.

I would love if the companies I intend/hope to develop custom apps for would get their own account, but I can just already now see it being at least a small obstacle for some who want "hands off".

What do you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload it yourself with your own company name.

You will be the one signing contracts with Apple, and you will be the one legally responsible for the apps.

Your name will be listed in the App Store as the developer.

You can put whatever you want in the copyright notice.

You can use whatever you want for the app name and description, so if you are developing the "Foobar" app for "XYZ Corporation", you can call it "XYZ Foobar" and in the app description you can say it is the official Foobar app for XYZ Corporation. (This assumes that XYZ Corporation has given you permission to use its trademarks.)

If it is a for-pay app, you will receive the payments.

If the other company eventually joins the Developer Program, you can transfer the app to them. (Note: This is a new feature. It wasn't possible until recently.)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I asked because on Apple's own site where developer signup is, I got the impression they wanted the companies you develop apps for should also signup. However, I guess I misread / misunderstood that. (It would also be an extremely odd clause since many non-tech companies would have trouble understanding why they would need their own developer ID) Thanks again! :)